# Running robot framework scripts from batch file: Import Library Error

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have been successfully writing robot framework test scripts (Using Eclipse IDE, RED Robot Editor) and now want to start scheduling them using windows batch files. However, when I try and run the script from a windows command prompt, I'm getting an error (see below). As I mentioned, the scripts worked fine. I would right click on the script file in Eclipse, then Run As -> Robot Test

Here's my error:

```
Importing test library 'Library' failed: ImportError: No module named Library
```

At script start up, here's what happens:

**__init__.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../Generic_Configurations/Import_File.robot
```

**Import_File.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Library
```

A couple preliminary questions:

- Is running my scripts from a command line dependent upon the eclipse environment (RED plugin)? If so, how do I tell the system to pull in those settings?
- Do I need to set any environmental variables so that the Library.py will be recognized?

Any comments/suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Are my scripts dependent upon the eclipse environment (RED plugin)?

Probably not. Robot itself is not dependent on an editing environment. However, it's possible that you are relying on some defaults or command line arguments supplied by your editing environment.

> Do I need to set any environmental variables so that the Library.py will be recognized?

Possibly. The rules for how robot finds libraries is well documented. See [Configuring where to search libraries and other extensions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#configuring-where-to-search-libraries-and-other-extensions) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: I'd be curious to see if anyone else is scripting RF with the Eclipse IDE and is pulling in custom python libraries. Did you get any errors? Can anyone provide sample RF windows batch files? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using the following at the top of my batch file:

```
set PYTHONPATH=Libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, try to add the python Libraries path in environment variable.
that should sol